# CakePHP: pass product_id value to checkout add page

Tags: cakephp

I'm pretty new to cakePHP and I've been stuck on this problem for a few days now. My Products index view displays a list of products we have in inventory and includes a "Checkout" action with every product that points to the Checkout/add view. The problem is the product_id from the product that needs to be checked out does not get passed to the add checkout page and I can't figure out how to make this happen. If anyone has any suggestions I could really use some help.

Here is my CheckoutController add action:

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Checkout->create();
        if ($this->Checkout->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The checkout has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The checkout could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $products = $this->Checkout->Product->find('list');
    $users = $this->Checkout->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('products', 'users'));
}
```

Checkout Add View

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Checkout');?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add Checkout'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('product_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('start_time');
    echo $this->Form->input('end_time');
    echo $this->Form->input('user_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('description');
?>
</fieldset>
```

Link from the Products index page

```
    <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Checkout'), array('controller' => 'Checkouts','action' => 'add', $product['Product']['id'])); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cake will pass the product_id as the first argument of your action; Default Cake 'Routes' will match this url;

```
/mycontroller/myaction/param1/param2/param3
```

To this action:

```
MycontrollerController::myaction(param1, param2, param3)
```

You can pass this value to the form by adding an argument to the add() action and adding it to the 'request' if the form is not posted. Like this;

```
public function add($productId = null) {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Checkout->create();
        if ($this->Checkout->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The checkout has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The checkout could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->data['Checkout']['product_id'] = $productId;
    }

    $products = $this->Checkout->Product->find('list');
    $users = $this->Checkout->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('products', 'users'));
}
```

This will automatically propagate the 'value' of the product_id drop down

Comment: Thank you so much! That second else statement with $this->request->data['Checkout']['product_id'] = $productId; was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

from your links on the products index page it seems that

`public function add()`

should read

`public function add($product_id)`

furthermore you should set the `$product_id` into the view, and also
fill it into the inputbox `echo $this->Form->input('product_id', array('value'=>$product_id));`